# Benefits of using a VPN for personal Internet browsing

Tags: networking, security, vpn, encryption

I can understand a **VPN** is good in this scenarios:

- For a **company network**, to allow encrypted connection among company computers and with the comany server.
- If you are connected to a **public Wi-Fi**, because other computers in the network won't be able to *see* what you're doing.
- If you're doing some *hacking* stuff in the Internet or, in general, if you do **not** want to **be tracked**.

What I can't understand is what are the benefits (if any) of using a VPN if I'm at home, using my personal computer in my private WiFi, and I'm just browsing the Internet in a normal way...

As far as I understand, I'm just adding a node in the route, to which the connection will be encrypted, but no from that node to the final site, right? Like this:

> *Without VPN*:
>   **My Router** ==================== *not encrypted* =====================**> Unsecure Site**
>   *With VPN*:
>   **My Router** ===== *encrypted* ====**> My VPN Server** ==== *not encrypted* ====**> Unsecure Site**

So is there any benefit of this?

Comment: For scenario 3, you might want to check [this](http://torrentfreak.com/which-vpn-services-take-your-anonymity-seriously-2014-edition-140315/) out if you're considering buying a VPN.

Comment: If you were in China you'd understand why. But in general you use it if you don't want to be tracked, or you want to appear like you're someplace else.  You don't need to be "hacking" to not want to be located. Really, if you can't figure out why you'd need it, then you don't need it.  It's very person/scenario-specific.  VTC at opinion-based.

Comment: @techie007, in fact I need the VPN because I want to avoid geolocation to watch TV :) I ask this to know the benefits of keeping connected to the VPN when i'm not watching TV (Note that I have my own VPN server in a rented VPS)

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the security of your home wi-fi router, are relatively convinced none of your neighbors is a potential bored hacker, and trust your internet provider - than you have no need for using VPN at home.

A VPN will add another layer of security, but will most probably slow down most common internet activities. I'd use it for the cases you specified above (with the exception of #3 - if you intend to violate the law, be aware of the fact they may still get to you, if they know your VPN provider - all depending on the provider's data-retention policy).

Comment: If you're hacking stuff, you should probably use something like Tor instead. :P

Comment: Could you explain in detail your sentence ***if you trust your internet provider***, please? Now my ISP can *sniff* my internet browing, but with a VPN, my VPS provider can do it, right? Why should I trust more a cheap hosting company than a big ISP? Thanks!

Comment: Those cheap, local ISPs are sometimes much better at fighting for your rights against encompassing government data collection activities. All I said is VPN usage is driven by trust (or lack thereof): you do not trust public wi-fi, you do not trust your employer, do you trust your ISP? If so - no need for VPN at home.